# why my js timer does not update when the time ended?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

my js timer is not being updated after the time ended.

this is my code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2 id="Bucharest"></h2>
  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

js:

```
var Bucharest = new Date("April 26, 2023 13:50:00").getTime();
var Bucharestinterval = setInterval(function() {
  var Bucharestnow = new Date().getTime();
  var Bucharestdistance = Bucharest - Bucharestnow;

  var Bucharestdays = Math.floor(Bucharestdistance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var Bucharesthours = Math.floor(
    (Bucharestdistance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
  );
  var Bucharestminutes = Math.floor(
    (Bucharestdistance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)
  );
  var Bucharestseconds = Math.floor((Bucharestdistance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("Bucharest").innerHTML =
    Bucharestdays +
    "d " +
    Bucharesthours +
    "h " +
    Bucharestminutes +
    "m " +
    Bucharestseconds +
    "s ";

  if (Bucharestinterval < 0) {
    clearInterval(Bucharestinterval);
    document.getElementById("Bucharest").innerHTML = "Let's go Bucharest!!!";
  }
}, 1);
```

i do not understand why it is not working as it should be... it should clear it and show my message. but it is not.

here is the the code in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rho1gcau/7/

Answer (score 1):

Someone already answered this, you're checking `Bucharestinterval` instead of `Bucharestdistance` to clear the interval.

A few other suggestions:

) don't set the interval to 1ms, this takes up alot of resources. If your timer is only to the second, updating every half second will be more than enough to stay accurate.

) if you have a bunch of related variables, consider building an object to store all of the data in one place.

Here's an example that produces the same output with only two variables.

```js
let time = {
  target: (new Date("April 26, 2023 13:50:00")).getTime(),
  difference: (formated) => {      
    if (formated) {
      let diff = (time.target - (new Date()).getTime()) / 1000; //convert to seconds, since we're not using ms
      return `${Math.floor(diff / 86400)}d ${Math.floor(diff / 3600) % 24}h ${Math.floor(diff / 60) % 60}m ${Math.floor(diff % 60)}s`;
    } else {
     return time.target -  (new Date()).getTime();
    }
  }
};

time.interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (time.difference() < 0) {
    clearInterval(time.interval);
    document.getElementById("Bucharest").innerHTML = "Let's go Bucharest!!!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Bucharest").innerHTML = time.difference(true);
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<h2 id="Bucharest"></h2>
```